# "0.5" cannot be casted to Long groovy

Tags: ajax, groovy, casting

i send with javascript a String value to grails server , the value is : "0.5"

```
$.post(myURL,{scale:"0.5"},fnPost);
```

When i casts it as following :

```
 Long scale= params?.scale as Long ;
```

i get :

```
For input string: "0.5". Stacktrace follows:

    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.5"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:419)
        at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:525)
```

Really, it is strange in groovy to see "0.5" cannot be casted to Long !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.5 is a double. You cannot cast it to `Long`. You need to cast it to `Double` or `BigDecimal` (default in Groovy)

```
assert "0.5" as BigDecimal == 0.5G
assert "0.5" as Double == 0.5D
assert "5" as Long == 5L
```